# unity home quicklist not working

Tags: unity, home-directory, quicklists

hello i have tried adding some quicklists to the unity launcher i added some to the gnome-terminal and they work fine added some to the nautilus-home but cannot get them to display here is my .desktop file

```
    [Desktop Entry]
Name=Home Folder
Comment=Open your personal folder
TryExec=nautilus
Exec=nautilus --no-desktop
Icon=user-home
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
Type=Application
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Core;
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=nautilus
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=general
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=nautilus
X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=bin;Documents;Downloads;Pictures;Video;Music;Ubuntu One;src;

[bin Desktop Shortcut Group]
Name=bin
Exec=nautilus bin
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[Documents Desktop Shortcut Group]
Name=Documents
Exec=nautilus Documents
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[Downloads Desktop Shortcut Group]
Name=Downloads
Exec=nautilus Downloads
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[Pictures Desktop Shortcut Group]
Name=Pictures
Exec=nautilus Pictures
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[Video Desktop Shortcut Group]
Name=Video
Exec=nautilus Video
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[Music Desktop Shortcut Group]
Name=Music
Exec=nautilus Music
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[Ubuntu One Desktop Shortcut Group]
Name=Ubuntu One
Exec=nautilus Ubuntu\ One
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[src Desktop Shortcut Group]
Name=src
Exec=nautilus src
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things wrong - here is a suggested revision:

```
[Desktop Entry]

Name=Home Folder
Comment=Open your personal folder
TryExec=nautilus
Exec=nautilus --no-desktop
Icon=user-home
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
Type=Application
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Core;
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=nautilus
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=general
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=nautilus

X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=bin;Documents;Downloads;Pictures;Video;Music;UbuntuOne;src;

[bin Shortcut Group]
Name=bin
Exec=nautilus bin
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[Documents Shortcut Group]
Name=Documents
Exec=nautilus Documents
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[Downloads Shortcut Group]
Name=Downloads
Exec=nautilus Downloads
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[Pictures Shortcut Group]
Name=Pictures
Exec=nautilus Pictures
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[Video Shortcut Group]
Name=Video
Exec=nautilus Video
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[Music Shortcut Group]
Name=Music
Exec=nautilus Music
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[UbuntuOne Shortcut Group]
Name=Ubuntu One
Exec=nautilus "Ubuntu One"
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[src Shortcut Group]
Name=src
Exec=nautilus src
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

Suggested changes:

- the group names (the bits between the square brackets) cannot have spaces
- I've quoted "Ubuntu One" - not sure if necessary but makes it easier to read.

Comment: Thank you can not believe i didn't notice that frustration can make you blind thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Two things,

1. You have a tab between the "T" and "arget..." in your "bin" entry.
2. I could be wrong, but I don't think the shortcut group entries can have spaces. Try making "Ubuntu One" into "UbuntuOne" in the `X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts` property and changing the corresponding entry to

`[Ubuntu One Desktop Shortcut Group]`

`Name=Ubuntu One`

`Exec=nautilus Ubuntu\ One`

`TargetEnvironment=Unity`

Edit: You also have a tab at the start of your file which may pose problem.

Comment: thanks for your reply but the tab in-between target was a typo while pasting and i have tried the same config with only Documents shortcut group and it still doesn't work i did have this working but recently done a clean install and cannot get this to work now but strangely it's working fine on the terminal and other icons just not home.